# a method of class is not working in remote web server but working locally

Tags: java, class, jsp, webserver, server

I have developed a jsp (web application) in which there is a class package vdb containing class Db whose source is below and jsp files are using the method `connect()`  which return Connection object and `year()` which return a integer value.

method `connect()` works well in both case (in remote server or localhost) but the method `year()` is working well in case of local host but in remote server(openshift) its not working.

FILE Db.java

```
package vdb;

import java.sql.*;

public class Db {
public static synchronized  Connection connect()
{
    Connection con=null;
    try{
    String url    =  "jdbc:mysql://1xx.x.xx.x:xx06/";
        String db     =  "mydb";
        String driver =  "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String user   = "adminaz";
        String pass   = "mypassword";
          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,user,pass);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
    return con;
}

public static int year()
{
int y=0;
ResultSet rs=null;
try
{
    Connection con=connect();
Statement st=con.createStatement();
rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(START) FROM SESSION");
    rs.next();
y=rs.getInt(1);
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
    return y;
}
}
```

File index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*;"pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% int y= vdb.Db.year();%>
 <%out.println(" CURRENT YEAR "+y);%>
```

What is the problem with this or error.How to overcome.

Comment: 1) Please indent your code so that it is readable. 2) add the stacktrace

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is it throwing an exception? Returning an unexpected value? Returning no value? Is the server accessing the same DB as you are accessing locally? If not, are both DB's populated with the same data?

Comment: How to get stacktrace  generated by class file in web server? locally i get stacktrace from tomcat output but don't know how to from remote web server.

Comment: it throw exception but i don't know which exception. how do i know or in case of jsp page ii use to print using out.println(ex); but don't know how to see from a java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the code.
Problem is with the case of table name used.
local host is on WINDOW OS while remote web server(OPENSHIFT) is Linux based and in Linux OS by default in mysql table names are case sensitive,
The exception caused due to the case mismatch.

In linux by default mysql queries are case sensitive but in window it is not.